# Tensorflow: How to inverse model.predict()?

Tags: tensorflow

Assuming I have a function: x -> y which I model with tensorflow:

I would like to inverse the model prediction going from y -> x (going back to find a probable input from the input layer)

I know that I can call something like model.predict(x) to predict y. 
Is there a way to do inverseModel.predictInput(y) = x ?